# The consistency ratio of the upward, downward, and equal directions of y_true and y_pred

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Assuming we have a dataframe `df`:

```
          date  y_true  y_pred1  y_pred2
0    2017-1-31    6.42    -2.35    15.57
1    2017-2-28   -2.35    15.57     6.64
2    2017-3-31   15.57     6.64     7.61
3    2017-4-30    6.64     7.61    10.28
4    2017-5-31    7.61     7.61     6.34
5    2017-6-30   10.28     6.34     4.88
6    2017-7-31    6.34     4.88     7.91
7    2017-8-31    6.34     7.91     6.26
8    2017-9-30    7.91     6.26    11.51
9   2017-10-31    6.26    11.51    10.73
10  2017-11-30   11.51    10.73    10.65
11  2017-12-31   10.73    10.65    32.05
```

I want to calculate the ratio of the **upward, downward, and equal consistency** of two consecutive months of data in two columns, and use it as an evaluation metric of the time series forecast results. The direction of the current month to previous month ratio: **up** means the current month value minus the previous month value is positive, similarly, **down** and `equal` means negative and 0, respectively.

I calculated the results for the sample data using the following function and code, note that we do not include the yellow rows in the calculation of the final ratio, because the `y_true_dir` for these rows is either `null` or `0`:

[image]

```
def cal_arrays_direction(value):
    if value > 0:
        return 1
    elif value < 0:
        return -1
    elif value == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return np.NaN
    
df['y_true_diff'] = df['y_true'].diff(1).map(cal_arrays_direction)
df['y_pred1_diff'] = df['y_pred1'].diff(1).map(cal_arrays_direction)
df['y_pred2_diff'] = df['y_pred2'].diff(1).map(cal_arrays_direction)

df['y_true_y_pred1'] = np.where((df['y_true_diff'] == df['y_pred1_diff']), 1, 0)
df['y_true_y_pred2'] = np.where((df['y_true_diff'] == df['y_pred2_diff']), 1, 0)

dir_acc_y_true_pred1 = df['y_true_y_pred1'].value_counts()[1] / (df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()[-1] 
+ df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()[1])
print(dir_acc_y_true_pred1)

dir_acc_y_true_pred2 = df['y_true_y_pred2'].value_counts()[1] / (df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()[-1] 
 + df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()[1])
print(dir_acc_y_true_pred2)
```

Out:

```
0.2
0.4
```

But I wonder how could I convert it into a function (similar to `MSE`, `RMSE`, etc. in `sklearn`) to make it's easier to use, thanks!

```
def direction_consistency_acc(y_true, y_pred):
     ...
     return dir_acc_ratio
```

**Update 1:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3803, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1577, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1587, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1.0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\code\stacked model_2022-11-08.py", line 353, in <module>
    run_model(df)
  File "..\code\stacked model_2022-11-08.py", line 258, in run_model
    out1 = direction_consistency_acc(preds['y_true'], preds[['y_pred1','y_pred2',
  File "..\code\stacked model_2022-11-08.py", line 245, in direction_consistency_acc
    dir_acc_y_true_pred = preds[f'y_true_{col}'].eq(1).sum() / (s[-1] + s[1])
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 981, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1089, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Update 2:**

I `print(df['y_true_diff'].value_counts())` while runing `direction_consistency_acc(df['y_true'], df[['y_pred1','y_pred2']])`:

```
...
2021-05-31
-1.0    4
 1.0    2
Name: y_true_diff, dtype: int64
2021-06-30
-1.0    5
 1.0    1
Name: y_true_diff, dtype: int64
2021-07-31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3803, in get_loc
-1.0    6
Name: y_true_diff, dtype: int64
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1577, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1587, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1.0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "..\code\stacked model_2022-11-08.py", line 353, in <module>
        run_model(df)
      File "..\code\stacked model_2022-11-08.py", line 258, in run_model
        out1 = direction_consistency_acc(preds['y_true'], preds[['y_pred1','y_pred2',
      File "..\code\stacked model_2022-11-08.py", line 245, in direction_consistency_acc
        dir_acc_y_true_pred = preds[f'y_true_{col}'].eq(1).sum() / (s[-1] + s[1])
      File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 981, in __getitem__
        return self._get_value(key)
      File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1089, in _get_value
        loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
      File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
        raise KeyError(key) from err
    KeyError: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom function, instead custom function use [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and instead `.value_counts()[1]` compare by `1` and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
#y_true - Series, y_pred - DataFrame
def direction_consistency_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    df['y_true_diff'] = np.sign(y_true.diff(1))
    s = df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()    

    out = []    
    for col in y_pred.columns:
        df[f'y_{col}_diff'] = np.sign(df[col].diff(1))
        df[f'y_true_{col}'] = np.where((df['y_true_diff'] == df[f'y_{col}_diff']), 1, 0)
        dir_acc_y_true_pred = df[f'y_true_{col}'].eq(1).sum() / (s[-1] + s[1])
        out.append(dir_acc_y_true_pred)
        
    return out
        
out = direction_consistency_acc(df['y_true'], df[['y_pred1','y_pred2']])
print(out)
[0.2, 0.4]
```

Alternative without new columns:

```
#y_true - Series, y_pred - DataFrame
def direction_consistency_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_diff = np.sign(y_true.diff(1))
    s = y_true_diff.value_counts()    

    out = []    
    for col in y_pred.columns:
        y_true = y_true_diff == np.sign(df[col].diff(1))
        dir_acc_y_true_pred = y_true.eq(1).sum() / (s[-1] + s[1])
        out.append(dir_acc_y_true_pred)
        
    return out
        
out = direction_consistency_acc(df['y_true'], df[['y_pred1','y_pred2']])
print(out)
[0.2, 0.4]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing these two awsome solutions, much efficient and conciser than mine.

Comment: Hello @jezrael, I tested with new data, it raised an error: `KeyError: 1` (I updated the full error in the end of this question), any ideas regarding this issue? :)

Comment: @ahbon - Is possible columns names are  floats `1.0` and expected is `1` ?

Comment: I checked, no column name is `1` or `1.0`.

Comment: @ahbon - what is `s` for failed solution? Seems there is no `1` value in index (because no `1` in y_true_diff), so raise error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I updated the full error in the end of this question again. I printed `s` (what does `s` stand for?), the reason seems to be that if `s` is only `-1`, the function will raise an error. For example, `2021-07-31`, the number of `-1` is `6`, while other months have both `1` and `-1`.

Comment: @ahbon - whats happens if not exist `-1` ? then should be `NaN` or `0` ? Then add `df['y_true_diff'].value_counts().reindex([1,-1])` for `NaN` or `df['y_true_diff'].value_counts().reindex([1,-1], fill_value=0)` for `0`

Answer (score 0):

My updated answer to this question:

```
def cal_arrays_direction(value):
    if value > 0:
        return 1
    elif value < 0:
        return -1
    elif value == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return np.NaN


def direction_consistency_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    df['y_true_diff'] = y_true.diff(1).map(cal_arrays_direction)
    df['y_pred_diff'] = y_pred.diff(1).map(cal_arrays_direction)
    df['y_true_pred_consis'] = np.where((df['y_true_diff'] == df['y_pred_diff']), 1, 0)
    dir_acc_ratio = df['y_true_pred_consis'].value_counts()[1] / (df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()[-1] 
    + df['y_true_diff'].value_counts()[1])
    return dir_acc_ratio

direction_consistency_acc(df['y_true'], df['y_pred1'])
```

Out:

```
0.2
```